# Can't Create Minified JavaScript Library for Web With webpack & Babel Without require() Being Output

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I'd like to use the latest JavaScript constructs not supported by all browsers so I've turned to webpack and Babel.

My code contains no requires but the output does. This causes
`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` when output is loaded in a browser.

### `.babelrc`

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env"
  ]
}
```

### `webpack.config.js`

```
const MinifyPlugin = require('babel-minify-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  target: 'web',
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './uuuu.js',
  output: { filename: 'uuuu.min.js' },   
  plugins: [
    new MinifyPlugin(
      {},
      {
        minifyPreset: require('babel-preset-minify')
      }
    )
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

What to do?

Answer (score -2):

I have had great experiences using the angular cli to build NPM JavaSscript libraries even if they are not Angular projects. You get the awesome build and test pipeline and can remove the Angular dependencies to create generic JavaScript libraries.

type

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

then

```
ng new my-lib --create-application=false
```

cd into the newly created folder and create a library

```
ng generate library my-lib
```

Change into the folder projects/my-lib and remove the Angular dependencies from peerDependencies in the package.json folder and remove the demo Angular component, module and service.

Now you have a world class TypeScript project ready to build and deploy to NPM.

Type

```
ng build my-lib
```

then change into dist/my-lib and type

```
npm publish
```

Why try and hand roll a build and test pipeline when you can have the experience of the Angular team behind you?

Comment: Uhhhhhhh. Well let's just say I'm not using TypeScript.

Comment: You realise that all ES6 is valid TypeScript?

Comment: All JavaScript is TypeScript so you actually are using TypeScript!

Comment: "I'd like to use the latest JavaScript constructs not supported by all browsers" so why not use TypeScript?